# Select row minumum from selection of columns using pmin

Tags: r, dplyr

given a sample df (real data contains >100 columns)

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame( x1 = runif(10),
                  x2 = runif(10),
                  y1 = runif(10),
                  y2 = runif(10) 
                  )
```

If i want the minumum value of all columns containing an 'x', the following will work:

```
df %>% mutate( minx = pmin( x1, x2, na.rm = TRUE ) )
          x1         x2         y1         y2       minx
1  0.2524359 0.66834400 0.42970192 0.89407768 0.25243588
2  0.8854106 0.40131771 0.10842259 0.08260381 0.40131771
```

However, when i want to select all columns containing an 'x' with contains(), but the following fails....

```
df %>% mutate( minx = pmin( contains("x"), na.rm = TRUE ) )
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: Variable context not set.
```

Why is it not possible to use contains() to select columns for use with pmap? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How about this? `df$minx <- apply(df[,grepl('x', names(df))], 1, min)`

Comment: I don't know tidyverse  but IIRS, `contains` is a `select` function helper and not meant to be used in `mutate`.

Comment: @Prem should be `2` for a columwise apply.

Comment: @count isn't OP interested in rowwise operation?

Comment: @Prem I thought columwise, but that's an easy fix with your `apply` solution ;)

Comment: `conains()` is only usable within `select()`, you have to use `mutate_at()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is one option

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   select(contains("x")) %>%
   reduce(pmin) %>%
   mutate(df, minx = .)
```

---

Or as @Wimpel mentioned in the comments, the `select` can be nested within the `mutate` call

```
df %>%
   mutate(minx = select(., contains("x")) %>% 
                    reduce(pmin, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: This works flawless, also for my production data! The tidyverse-syntax fits in perfectly with the rest of my code.
 Thank you very much!

Comment: I order to be able to create the `mutate = minx` in the data in one row of code, without it interfering with my data.frame, I adjusted the code above a bit:  
`df2 <- df %>% <other code here> %>% mutate( minx = select( df, contains ("x" ) ) %>% reduce( pmin, na.rm = TRUE ) ) %>% <other code here>`

Answer (score 3):

Using base `R`

```
df$minx <- apply(df[, grepl('x', names(df))], 1, min)
```

`dplyr` solution could be

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(minx = do.call(pmin, select(df, matches("x."))))
```

Comment: You can do the same thing in base R `do.call(pmin, df[grepl('x', names(df))])`. Using `apply` with a 1 margin is usually a bad decision

Comment: Also a working solution, but the piped code-answer provided by @akrun fits my needs better.  Thank you very much for your answer though.. learning every day :)